# Paragraphing in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, cs5

I'm using CS5 Photoshop. When I use the Type Tool and put some text into a picture, as I press ENTER to start a new paragraph within the same block of text it just de-selects the text and doesn't begin a new paragraph. I've been able to press ENTER to go to a new line of text on other computers. Am I missing an option?

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: try shift + enter?

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> in Photoshop means "Commit" not "line feed".

For a line feed, use the <kbd>**Return**</kbd> key not the <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

Type <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to force a line break in a text area.

---

You can also set line breaks by resizing the text box.

Answer (score -4):

Once you select the Text Tool and type letters if you miss also it will create the layer so Just double click on the text [T]layer.So that you can edit within the  layer.

Comment: Is this even English?